# Linux screen(or java) with different date of system

Tags: centos7, java, timezone, date

I having a problem with screen on Centos 7. The system time is correct but on screen application theres a diference of 3 hours.

The system output(correct):

```
[root@Server ~]# date
Ter Fev 23 01:27:11 BRT 2016
```

And the screen outputs running a java application:

```
[04:27:09 INFO]: ...
```

This is a screen or java issue?

Comment: What is the timezone in both cases ?

Comment: Its São_Paulo/America

Answer (score 0):

The application is disregarding the system time zone and displaying the time in UTC.

In your timezone, the summer time had just ended, so your time zone was UTC-0300. This corresponds to the time displayed by your application.